# Spring property loading depending on class that invokes

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a class A which contains a property

```
class A{  
  String valA;  
}
```

I have two classes B and C which have a reference to class A

```
class B{  
   @Autowired  
   private A aaa;  
}


class C{  
   @Autowired  
   private A aaa;  
}
```

The valA in class A would be property driven and should depend on which class in actually invoking it.

If class B is invoking it , it should be some thing like b.property defined in a property file
and for class C the value would be c.property

Is this possible to do this without using an XML configuration and only annotation , SPEL etc

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean, "invoking it"?  What's being invoked?

Comment: invoking means that both class B and class C has an instance of class A and can call some methods in class A. Depending upon which class is calling those methods I would like the value of valA in class A to have different values

Answer (score 0):

You need two different instances of A (one for B and one for C), because you can not change the value of an property in A depended on the way A is invoked*.

Have a look at the [concept of qualifies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) to see how they can be used to distinguishes between two instances of the same class.

*footenote* * *of course you can change the parameter in A depended on how A is invoked, but this requires a lot of technical code and some hacks. And should be not the code you want to have in your spring app.*